# Different ways of creating files

Tags: java

There are methods for creating files in `java.io.File` (like `createNewFile()` or `mkdir()`). Are there other ways of creating files in Java SE using "standard" API?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a `FileOuputStream`, the file is created, if it does not exist, although this is not guaranteed:

> A file output stream is an output stream for writing data to a File or to a FileDescriptor. Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the underlying platform.

Answer (score 1):

`FileOutputStream` can be used to create a file as shown below

```
FileOutputStream fos = new  FileOutputStream("myfile");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("myfile"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrintWriter in conjunction with FileWriter such as PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("FileName", false)); writing to blank file or BufferedWriter works with FileWriter as well, such as BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("FileName"));